# For report can't access Contact data for Campaign object that has lookup to Contact

Tags: reporting, contact, campaign

We wanted to repurpose the standard object "Campaign" so that it could be used to track what we call "ELAW Fellowships".

We added a new lookup field in campaign that does a lookup to the Contact object.

When I go to reports and create a new report of the report type "Campaigns with Contacts" (non custom report type) and then try to return all Campaigns of Record Type "ELAW Fellowships" no data is returned

[image]

I know there are Campaigns with record type "ELAW Fellowships" though because I can run a report of report type "Campaign" and have the Record Type be "ELAW Fellowship" then I get all the expected results (blurred for privacy).

[image]

I then tried creating a custom Report Type of Campaigns with Contacts
[image]

and when I create I create a new report from this report type the objects used says "Campaign" and "Campaign Member".
[image]

From the custom report type I created this should be "Contact" rather than "Campaign Member", but I tried to run the report anyways and get no results.

I just need a couple of fields from the Contact associated with the Campaign but I can't seem to get access to them.

Please advise me!

[image]

Comment: With a Lookup from Campaign to Contact, you're looking for a report type of Contacts with Campaigns. The standard Campaigns with Contacts type shows you Contacts that are members of the Campaign. If your goal with ELAW Fellowships is to create and manage a list of people who apply for or receive a fellowship, along with a Status and maybe other info, then you want to use standard campaign membership functionality. Your custom lookup relates exactly one Contact with a Campaign.

Comment: I looked for a report type of "Contacts with Campaigns" and couldn't find one that already existed.  I tried to create a new Report Type of "Contacts with Campaigns" and the only related record type for Contact with the word Campaign in it was "Campaign history".  Just to be clear the only thing connecting Campaign is a lookup to Contact on the Campaign object (This lookup finds the Contact who was involved in the fellowship).

Comment: You probably need to create a custom report type - seems adding the field didn't do it automatically. Or, perhaps you gave the field or relationship a non-standard name. If you called the child relationship Fellowships, then maybe there's a report for Contacts with Fellowships. Are you aggregating Opportunities or Contact Members under the Campaign/Fellowship? If not, why use Campaigns?